# On Designing Some Optimal Control Problems

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, oc.optimization-and-control, stability

In the context of a dynamical systems, some states may not be attainable with scalar controls from $L^1(0,T)$, but they may be reachable with feedback controls.

If we know that the system is null controllable with feedback control (potentially outside of $L^1(0,T)$), the goal is to determine how optimal control theory can be utilized to find these controllers.

What are the available strategies and resources that can help achieve this objective?

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of such a case?

Comment: For example, consider
$$\dot y(x,t)=\Delta y(x,t)+p(t)y(x,t) \quad in \ \Omega \times (0,T)$$
subject to the initial condition $y(0)=y_0$ in $\Omega$, and the boundary condition $y=0$ on $\Gamma$.

It has been shown by Ouzahra M. in "Finite-time control for the bilinear heat equation" that for any $y_0 \in L^2(\Omega)\backslash \{0\}$, the dynamical system is null controllable by a feedback.

However, in "Controllability for Distributed Bilinear Systems," J. M. Ball has demonstrated that it is impossible to reach the null state through a control from $L^1(0,T)$.